# C++ assigning member function pointer to non-member function pointer

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

Hy everyone,
I am quite new with OOP in C++ [go easy on me :) ] and I am trying to build a class in which a class member function needs to be taken from outside the class. I thought of doing it by declaring a function pointer member and creating a member function that takes as input a pointer to the function that I want to include in the class and sets the member pointer to the input.

This is how I am trying to do it:

```
class A{
    std::vector<double> *(A::*obj) (std::vector<double> x);
    void set_obj(std::function<std::vector<double>>* Po);
};

void A::set_obj(std::function<std::vector<double>>* Po){
    this->obj = Po;
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
error: Assigning to 'std::vector<double> *(A::*)(std::vector<double>)' from incompatible type 'std::function<std::vector<double>> *'
```

I can also add that I am open to alternative solutions which do not imply the use of function pointers.

Comment: this->obj is one type and Po is a completely different type. How did you want it to work?

Comment: This looks like the Y of an XY problem. What is the X?

Comment: Let's assume you could do this -- how would you attempt to call your member function?  You need an object to call the member function on, so how would the syntax look like for the function call?  That's right, you're stuck, because the "ordinary" function call syntax doesn't have an object to worry about, but the member function requires an object.  You will see that the call to a member function using a pointer is `object->*func_pointer(args);`.  So where are you going to get `object` from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues. First, 'pointer-to-member' types are an advanced (and, dare I say, esoteric) feature for accessing member functions as pointers. Since you've got an `std::function` (which, when it comes down to it, is some sort of ordinary function, not a member function), you don't need pointer-to-member.

Second, you can't use ordinary function pointers since `std::function` is, again, more general. The former will *only* accept actual top-level functions (and closures which do not close around anything, which are trivially converted to top-level functions). The latter accepts top-level functions, closures, and functors. Now, in modern C++, you *want* `std::function`, since it's more general and abstract and just generally less confusing. So I suggest making the member variable have `std::function` type.

```
using MyFunction = std::function<std::vector<double>(std::vector<double>)>;

class A{
    MyFunction obj;
    void set_obj(MyFunction obj);
};

void A::set_obj(MyFunction obj){
    this->obj = std::move(obj);
}
```

I've also gotten rid of the raw pointer. You don't need it, and generally as you're learning C++ you should stay away from it. I've taken the argument by value, so that we can `std::move` it into the instance variable. We still copy the function into once when we call this member function, but [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) is always copy-assignable

> `std::function` satisfies the requirements of *CopyConstructible* and *CopyAssignable*.

Comment: Is there any reason to avoid passing `obj` by value and then using `this->obj = std::move(obj);`? Intuitively, that would allow "move-ctor, then move-assign" when we pass an xvalue, and the two moves could (likely?) be cheaper than one copy. (Or, alternatively, we could add a suitable overload `set_obj(MyFunction &&obj)`)

Comment: @chi Eecellent point, thanks! Edited.